# Go checking for the type of a custom Error

Tags: error-handling, go

I am having a hard time using a custom Error type in Go.
I read this [Blog post on Errors](http://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go)

So I tried this:

In my model.go I defined a custom error:

```
type ModelMissingError struct {
    msg string // description of error
}

func (e *ModelMissingError) Error() string { return e.msg }
```

In one of my methods I throw a custom error like this:

```
...
return Model{}, &ModelMissingError{"no model found for id"}
...
```

In the caller of that method I would like to check the error returned for its type and take action if it is in fact a `ModelMissingError`.

**How can I do this?**

I tried this:

```
if err == model.ModelMissingError
```

The result is `*type model.ModelMissingError is not an expression*`

Clearly I am missing something.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Reading the Blog post further exposes a bit of Go like this:

```
serr, ok := err.(*model.ModelMissingError)
```

This is the comma ok idiom, clearly I need to re do my [go lang tour](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15) <- UPDATED LINK

---- quoted from golang tour ----

*A type assertion provides access to an interface value's underlying concrete value.
t := i.(T)
This statement asserts that the interface value i holds the concrete type T and assigns the underlying T value to the variable t.
If i does not hold a T, the statement will trigger a panic.
To test whether an interface value holds a specific type, a type assertion can return two values: the underlying value and a boolean value that reports whether the assertion succeeded.*

Comment: Hello from the future! Here's the link to the relevant part of the tour that actually explains what's happening here. It would be great to (a) link this from the answer, and (b) quote the explanation directly in the answer. https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Comment: In golang 1.13+ to check the type of the error, use `errors.As` and to check the value `errors.Is`

Answer (score 58):

To check the **TYPE** of the error, use [`errors.As`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#As)

> `As` finds the first error in err's chain that matches target [...] ​An error matches target if the error's concrete value is assignable to the value pointed to by target

Of course type identity is a condition for assignability.

So it would look like:

```
target := &model.ModelMissingError{} 
if errors.As(err, &target) {
    fmt.Println(target) // no model found for id
}
```

Pay attention to the two uses of `&` in the example above. This is because:

> `As` panics if target is not a non-nil pointer to either a type that implements error, or to any interface type.

In your case, you declared `Error() string` method **on the pointer receiver**, therefore "a pointer to the type that implements the `error` interface" to satisfy `As` is `**ModelMissingError`. So you need to address twice.

---

The other method [`errors.Is`](https://pkg.go.dev/errors#Is) checks for **value** equality.

> An error is considered to match a target **if it is equal to that target** or if it implements a method Is(error) bool such that Is(target) returns true.

This is useful for example in case of fixed error values, e.g. errors declared as `var` or `const` like the standard library `io.EOF`. As an example:

```
var ErrModelMissing = errors.New("no model found for id")

func foo() {
    err := bar()
    if errors.Is(err, ErrModelMissing) {
        fmt.Println(err) // no model found for id
    }
}
```

---

Consider that the usefulness of Go 1.13 `errors.As` and `errors.Is` lies in error unwrapping. If you inspect the error at the top of an arbitrarily long call stack, you must remember that the original error may become wrapped into other errors while being bubbled up. Then directly checking for equality or type assignability is not enough.

```
    err1 := fmt.Errorf("wrapped: %w", &ModelMissingError{})
    target := &ModelMissingError{}
    fmt.Println(errors.As(err1, &target)) // true
    
    err2 := fmt.Errorf("wrapped: %w", FixedError)
    fmt.Println(errors.Is(err2, FixedError)) // true
    fmt.Println(err2 == FixedError) // false
```

Additionally, the package `github.com/pkg/errors` is compatible with `errors.As` and `errors.Is`:

```
// import pkgerr "github.com/pkg/errors"

err3 := pkgerr.Wrap(pkgerr.Wrap(&ModelMissingError{}, "wrapped 1"), "wrapped 2")
fmt.Println(errors.As(err3, &target)) // true
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/FEzggdBLCqq

---

Naturally, if you know for sure that the error is not wrapped, a good old type assertion works just as fine:

```
if myerr, ok := err.(*model.ModelMissingError); ok {
    // handle myerr
}
```

Answer (score 54):

I have manged to make an error assertion using the switch statement as follows:

```
 err := FuncModelMissingError()

 switch t := err.(type) {
 default:
     fmt.Println("not a model missing error")
 case *ModelMissingError:
     fmt.Println("ModelMissingError", t)
}
```

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 33):

Now with Go 1.13 we can use the following from the `errors` package:

```golang
if errors.Is(err, model.ModelMissingError) {...}
```

See the blog post: https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors

Comment: errors.Is() looks at the value of the error. Since the OP is looking for the type of the error, they would want to use errors.As()

Answer (score 7):

If you are Validating across types:

```
switch err := errorFromFunction(); err.(type) {
    case nil:
        fmt.Println("No Error Function Executed Successfully")
    case *ErrorType1:
        fmt.Println("Type1 Error: ", err)
    case *ErrorType2:
        fmt.Println("Type2 Error", err)
}
```

If you know the error and want to validate:

```
err, ok := err.(*ErrorType1)
```

Answer (score 7):

### For Short

- Sentinel errors - match with `errors.Is`
- Structured errors - match with `errors.As`

### Details

- Sentinel errors

  - Global error variables

  ```golang
  var ErrExist = errors.New("file already exists")
  var ErrPermission = errors.New("permission denied")
  ```

  - match with `errors.Is`

  ```golang
  if errors.Is(err, ErrNotExist) {
    createFile(..)
  }
  ```
- Structured errors

  - Custom error types

  ```golang
  type CustomError struct {
    Msg          string
  }

  func (e *CustomError) Error() string
  ```

  - Match with errors.As

  ```golang
  var cusErr *CustomError
  if errors.As(err, &cusErr) {
     fmt.Print(cusErr.Msg)
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know what the error type is, you can use the `reflect` package

```
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(err).Type())
```

or to get the full error chain

```
for err != nil {
  fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(err).Type())
  err = errors.Unwrap(err)
}
```

Comment: Answers the question how to identify error type.

Comment: `fmt.Sprintf("%T", err)` will do too