# errors.Is() doesn't function propertly

Tags: go

I pasted a section of code that was supposed to catch an `AllTopologyNodesDownError` error which doesn't work and I have no idea why.

```
func (sc *ServerConfig) addNodesToCluster(store *ravendb.DocumentStore) error {
        clusterTopology, err := sc.getClusterTopology(store)
        if errors.Is(err, &ravendb.AllTopologyNodesDownError{}) {
            for _, url := range sc.Url.List {
                    err = addNodeToCluster(store, url)
                    if err != nil {
                        return err
                    }
            }
        } else if err != nil {
            return err
        }
```

the structure of the `ravendb.AllTopologyNodesDownError` is

```
// AllTopologyNodesDownError represents "all topology nodes are down" error
type AllTopologyNodesDownError struct {
    errorBase
} 

type errorBase struct {
    wrapped  error
    ErrorStr string
}
```

[screen shot of the error when debugging the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laq6G.png)

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of text.

Comment: `errors.Is()` is false for this because the error is not and can never be the literal `&ravendb.AllTopologyNodesDownError{}` you provided. It looks like your `AllTopologyNodesDownError` is a type, not an instance, so you want `errors.As()`.

Comment: Hope these links help: https://go.dev/blog/go1.13-errors and https://peter.bourgon.org/blog/2019/09/11/programming-with-errors.html

Comment: related: [Go checking for the type of a custom Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23796543)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`errors.Is()` is used to tell if any error in the chain is the same *instance* as the provided error<sup>1</sup>, that can never be the case here because you provided a literal of your error type, no other code could hold that instance or a reference to it.

Your error looks like a type, to tell if any error in the chain is a given type you should use `errors.As()`:

```golang
clusterTopology, err := sc.getClusterTopology(store)
var errAllDown *AllTopologyNodesDownError
if errors.As(err, &errAllDown) {
    // err had an *AllTopologyNodesDownError in its
    // chain and errAllDown now contains it.
}
```

---

1. Can be overridden by implementing the `Unwrap()` interface which your error type does not.