# Error checking via errors.Is() golang function does not validate error type equality

Tags: go, error-handling

I am making dns checks via [this](https://github.com/miekg/dns) module.

```golang
m1 := new(dns.Msg)
m1.Question = make([]dns.Question, 1)
m1.SetQuestion(dns.Fqdn(host), dns.TypeA)
c := new(dns.Client)
in, _, err = c.Exchange(m1, resolverFull)
```

I am getting occasional timeout errors and by printing the error type I [see](https://pkg.go.dev/net#OpError) it is `*net.OpError`

However, this check

```golang
errors.Is(err, &net.OpError{})
```

never becomes true.

Trying with `errors.As` gave a `nil` pointer exception as

> *target must be interface or implement error

Why is the check failing since the error **is** a `*net.OpError` type and what is the correct way to go about it?

Comment: `errors.Is` checks for equality, and the error returned in not the same as the `*net.OpError` you are passing in.

Comment: @JimB `errors.Is()` does not _always_ check for equality; if a candidate error is of a type that implements an `Is()` method then `errors.Is()` will take the result of that.  It is more correct to say that `errors.Is()` checks for _equivalence_, where the criteria for equivalence is dependent on the implementation of the target error type.  In the case of `net.OpError` there is no `Is()` method implementation therefore equality is required for equiavalence _in this instance_.  This is not addressed in the answers you have linked to; please consider re-opening so it may be addressed here.

Comment: @Deltics, yes I could have mentioned that there is no `Is()` method, I was leaving that to the documentation. The newer answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68981088/32880) covers everything

Comment: @JimB if documentation could be relied on, 60% of StackOverflow likely wouldn't exist. :)  In any event, that answer is not the accepted answer so is likely to be overlooked.  Not that it helps anyways since it also repeats the mistake of stating that "`errors.Is()` tests for equality".  Yes, it also quotes the documentation which references the _optional_ `Is()` method implementation, but the answer does not expand on that, instead referencing `io.EOF` and `errors.New()` errors without any exploration of matching on equality vs non-equal equivalence.

Comment: What I also fail to understand is why my attempt to use `errors.As()` panics given that the target error **does** [implement](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.22.1:src/net/net.go;l=469) the `Error` interface, no?

Comment: @pkaramol: that is answered specifically by the first linked duplicate. `errors.As` cannot assign a value to your argument if you do not pass a pointer to it.